# Determining why loop is caught on specific spot in list using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, loops, web-scraping

Context: I'm trying to iterate over a list of links (single webpage, hundreds of links listed) using Selenium to click into the links then return to the page with the list. The script correctly identifies the list by the xpath, but for some reason the loop always picks this option in the list:

```
<a href="/display/reference/PowerForm+-+Adult+Ambulatory+Intake+History+Ortho+-+Form+Design+-+Excel">PowerForm - Adult Ambulatory Intake History Ortho - Form Design - Excel</a>
```

Here's the beginning of the list I'm trying to iterate over:
[Webpage links list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Yd7u.png)

After the script goes to that page, and returns to the list, it still selects that specific one to go back into and I have no idea why that one in particular. Please help!

Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
#below imports the ability to access keys/buttons on web pages
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
from time import sleep
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

#directing to desired wiki page
driver.get("https://businesslogin.cerner.com/?ReturnUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwiki.cerner.com%2Flogin.action%3Fos_destination%3D%252Fpages%252Fviewpage.action%253FspaceKey%253Dreference%2526title%253DClinical%25252520Content%25252520PowerForms%25252520Pages")

#clicking associate login button
login = driver.find_element_by_id("react-548405278")
login.click()

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "react-548405278"))
    )
    element.click()
    
except:
    time.sleep(2)

acceptcookies = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))
)
acceptcookies.click()
#at this point you should be at the desired wiki page with the list of links


#below accesses each link, opens the tinylink, and copies it
powerforms = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='main-content']/ul")
links = powerforms.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")

linkslist = []

for li in links:
    linkslist.append(li.text)
    continue

# WRITE LIST OF FORMS TO EXCEL FILE HERE
#workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('powerforms.tinylinks.xslx')

for link in links:

    try:
        link = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "main-content")))
        link.click()

        # clicks 'Share' button to open popout
        share = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'shareContentLink')))
        share.click()

        # clicks 'Copy' button to copy the tinylink to the clipboard
        copy = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'share-link-copy-button')))
        copy.click()

        driver.find_element_by_link_text("Clinical Content PowerForms Pages").click()
        
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Couldn't load element")
        continue
```

Comment: Side note: I'm new to stackoverflow so please just let me know if I should give more information or clarify better

Comment: What do you mean by "it still selects that specific one to go back into". Please show/describe the behavior/output you expect and show what you're actually getting.

Comment: in your `for link in links` loop you click the same element in each iteration because you search by id ('main-content').
btw, you don't need `continue` at the end of your loops

Comment: @Carcigenicate- the script always selects the <li> item that's noted above, and once it's in that link correctly copies the desired data, returns to the list and always selects that same <li> again instead of looping down

Comment: @MaximilianPeters - this might be the solution, but is there another way to specify the script to select the items in the list since they don't have their own ID's? possibly the presence of their href tag?